# A vertical Navigation bar with display:block on a link inside a <li> fill the entire width of the list item

Tags: css

For a vertical navigation nemu such as this one shown below,

```
            <ul id= "nav">
                <li>
                    <a href = "#"> Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href = "#"> France</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href = "#"> Italy</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href = "#"> Spain</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href = "#"> Eastern Mediterranean</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href = "#"> Islands</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

If i put

```
#nav a {
         display: block;
     }
```

This makes the link fill the ***entire width*** of the list item, turning it into a clickable button. The effect will become obvious when you add a background color later.

Before:
[image]

After adding the `display:block` property,

[image]

Why the same is not achievable by setting width : 100% on the `<a>` inside a `<li>`?

Comment: Because `a` is an `inline` element: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anchor element `<a>` is an inline element and doesn't adhere to box model concept. For any element to support the width/height, padding/margin appropriately you will have to force box model on that and that's what happens when you use `display:block;`

Read more about Box Model: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box_model

When an element is turned into block element by CSS, it automatically takes 100% width of the parent.

Few inline elements: span, a, small etc.
Block elements: div, p, li etc.

You can even alter block elements to behave like inline by adding css `display:inline` to it.